# Какого формата параметр "photo" надо передавать в функции VkApi saveWallPhoto()?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Пишу скрипт для постинга в vk.com с помощью VkApi
Написал функцию на python как указано в документации (https://vk.com/dev/upload_files?f=2.%20%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%83):

```
def log():
    api = vk_bot.log_in() # Логиним API
    upload_url = api.photos.getWallUploadServer(group_id=Settings.owner_id)  # Получаем ссылку для отправки POST запроса
    files = {'photo': open('img/img.jpg', 'rb')}
    req = requests.post(upload_url["upload_url"], files=files)  # Отправляем файл на сервер POST-запросом
    req_json = req.json()  # Парсим полученный после POST-запроса JSON
    save = api.photos.saveWallPhoto(group_id="143550839", server=req_json["server"], hash=req_json["hash"],
                                    photo=req_json["photo"])  # Сохраняем фотографию
```

*Но saveWallPhoto выдает ошибку:
vk.exceptions.VkAPIError: 121. Invalid hash. request_params = {'method': 'photos.saveWallPhoto', 'oauth': '1', 'server': '636920', 'hash': '9e709ad556250f8bdf8a60097e15ac22', 'group_id': '143550839', 'photo': '[{"photo":"0c19a83976:z","sizes":[["s","636920266","75a61","RVk73LMlNLw",54,75],["m","636920266","75a62","fN3OBSczx_Y",93,130],["x","636920266","75a63","UoxDrWt2ojA",430,604],["y","636920266","75a64","hpmMeddV6Uk",575,807],["z","636920266","75a65","aA0Fx_CzlFc",641,900],["o","636920266","75a66","KIuTyeat5-Q",130,183],["p","636920266","75a67","fdiw9AR0DXc",200,281],["q","636920266","75a68","6t3eBTmzdIg",320,449],["r","636920266","75a69","rK4uvmpD0-M",510,716]],"kid":"afa2131cca4d7f2d51c4bbccf6db9254","debug":"xszmzxzyzzzozpzqzrz"}]'}*